# How does the Schroder-Bernstein Theorem imply this?

Tags: set-theory

I'm reading a proof of the "Fundamental Theorem of Cardinal Arithmetic," that is, that for any  infinite set A, A is equinumerous to A x A (assuming the AC, as necessary).

Now, the background information doesn't seem relevant, but anyway, here it is. The proof proceeds as follows.  The author lets E be the set of bijections from subsets S of A onto S x S .  Then E is closed under chain unions, so by a maximal principle, E contains a maximal element f.  Now let M be the domain of f.  Then the author claims that A - M must be strictly smaller than M. (meaning, of course, that there is an injection from A - M onto a proper subset of M, but that there is no bijection from A - M onto M.)

Now's where I get lost.  To prove that A - M is smaller than M, the author argues by contradiction.  So suppose A - M were not smaller than M. The author states that "by the Bernstein-Schroder Theorem 2.1, A - M would include a subset M' of the same size as M." (I.e., M <= A - M, or M can be mapped injectively into A - M)

Maybe I'm stupid, but I don't see how this follows from the Schroder-Bernstein Theorem at all.  I know I could prove M <= A - M by using an AC argument--and of course, AC is assumed anyway--but this still bothers me.

The author seems to be asserting this proposition:

If B is a subset of A, then if A - B is not smaller than B, then B <= A - B.

Comment: Where are you reading this? It could be a typo...

Comment: Smullyan and Fitting's "Set Theory and the Continuum Problem."  You're right, it could be--maybe the reasoning just got swept under the rug? I believe it's true when the AC is assumed, as described above.

Comment: Did you check the errata pages? http://comet.lehman.cuny.edu/fitting/errata/errata.html

Comment: Yeah I did. It didn't show up. I have the Dover book. Thanks though.

Comment: I understand you do not want to (or cannot in that context) use $A\le B\lor B\le A$?

Comment: @Hagen: I understand the opposite. But the proof, as given in the post, uses the Cantor-Bernstein to conclude something which seems to be a consequence of the axiom of choice (in the form that you include in your post). And the question is how this is a consequence of the Cantor-Bernstein theorem, and not of the axiom of choice?

Comment: @Jrx: Can you give some more accurate reference, what page the proof appears in, and what is its number?

Comment: Yes: Ch. 9, Sec. 6, pg. 116. Theorem # 6.4

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't appear anywhere in the errata list. I'd send an email to the author and ask.

Comment: Yeah, that's my best bet. I'd actually given up on this book a while ago, because I'd encountered so many issues like this. But I guess it's kept me on my feet, so that's good.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of $A \setminus M$ we may as well consider an arbitrary subset $B$ of $A$.

The statement $B \prec A$, that $B$ is strictly smaller than $A$, is usually defined in the absence of AC to mean that $B \preceq A$ and $A \not \preceq B$.  That is, there is an injection $B \to A$ but no injection $A \to B$.

If it is *not* the case that $B \prec A$, then because $B \preceq A$ holds (as $B$ is a subset of $A$) we must have $A \preceq B$.  Therefore $B \approx A$ by the Cantor–Bernstein Theorem.

Comment: I think there's some confusion here about the problem I posed.  What you seem to have shown is that if B is a subset of A, then B is equinumerous to A--a statement which is very clearly false.  But indeed, it can never be the case that B < A is false, as B is a subset of A.

Comment: @Jrx I don't discount the possibility that I have misunderstood your question.  But I don't see how I "seem to have shown" that every subset $B$ of $A$ is equinumerous to $A$.  I just showed that it is _either_ strictly smaller than $A$, or else equinumerous to $A$ (and I think this might be what your book is showing, although I don't have a copy.)  I don't understand the last sentence of your comment.  The set $A$ is a subset of itself---are you saying that $A < A$? I'm not sure what that would mean.  What are you saying in terms of injections?